# Show only some series in HighCharts spline chart

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I have a highchart with chart type as spline

In this chart, I have about 36 series data, but the problem is that showing 36 series in one single chart is really difficult to understand and moreover almost all have almost similar data.

My question is that how can we show only selected or pre-defined series instead of showing all series at once, which is done by default by highcharts.

Also, I do not want to change my API which is fetching the JSON data, is there any way to do it from front end itself ?

```js
$(function(){
$('#highchart_1').highcharts({
   chart:{
    type:'spline',
    zoomType: 'x'
   },
   title: {
    text: 'Pregnant Women Overview',
            x: -20 //center
        },
        subtitle: {
         text: 'Source:something.com',
         x: -20
        },
        xAxis: {
         categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun','Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },
        yAxis: {
         title: {
          text: 'Pregnant Women ( No. )'
         },
         plotLines: [{
          value: 0,
          width: 1,
          color: '#808080'
         }]
        },
        tooltip: {
         valueSuffix: ''
        },
        legend: {
         layout: 'vertical',
         align: 'right',
         verticalAlign: 'middle',
         borderWidth: 0
        },
        series:[
{
name: 1000,
data: [7,4,1,0,0,1,3,6,2,2,8,7]
},
{
name: 1001,
data: [6,10,1,1,0,0,0,2,3,2,2,5]
},
{
name: 1002,
data: [
0,
0,
35,
0,
1,
0,
0,
0,
0,
0,
0,
0
]
},
{
name: 1003,
data: [
2,
1,
4,
0,
0,
1,
1,
1,
0,
4,
4,
6
]
},
{
name: 1005,
data: [
0,
0,
0,
15,
0,
0,
0,
0,
0,
0,
0,
0
]
},
{
name: 1006,
data: [
8,
8,
3,
2,
1,
0,
2,
2,
1,
2,
1,
5
]
},
{
name: 1007,
data: [
8,
9,
0,
1,
0,
1,
2,
1,
2,
7,
1,
2
]
},
{
name: 1008,
data: [
3,
4,
4,
0,
0,
1,
3,
0,
2,
4,
3,
6
]
},
{
name: 1009,
data: [
6,
6,
6,
0,
0,
0,
0,
1,
2,
0,
10,
8
]
},
{
name: 1011,
data: [
0,
0,
4,
0,
0,
0,
0,
0,
0,
0,
0,
0
]
},
{
name: 1012,
data: [
5,
7,
11,
3,
0,
0,
0,
0,
2,
1,
5,
7
]
},
{
name: 1013,
data: [
4,
4,
1,
0,
0,
0,
0,
0,
3,
3,
4,
6
]
},
{
name: 1015,
data: [
2,
6,
53,
0,
0,
0,
0,
0,
0,
1,
2,
0
]
},
{
name: 1016,
data: [
12,
8,
0,
1,
0,
0,
1,
2,
5,
1,
6,
7
]
},
{
name: 1017,
data: [
0,
1,
25,
0,
2,
0,
0,
0,
0,
0,
0,
0
]
},
{
name: 1019,
data: [
7,
9,
6,
7,
0,
0,
0,
1,
2,
1,
5,
11
]
},
{
name: 1020,
data: [
0,
2,
0,
9,
2,
0,
0,
0,
0,
0,
2,
0
]
},
{
name: 1021,
data: [
0,
4,
1,
2,
0,
0,
1,
0,
0,
3,
2,
2
]
},
{
name: 1022,
data: [
0,
0,
1,
0,
20,
0,
0,
0,
0,
0,
0,
0
]
},
{
name: 1025,
data: [
5,
2,
9,
0,
1,
2,
6,
1,
4,
1,
6,
4
]
},
{
name: 1026,
data: [
1,
0,
1,
12,
0,
1,
0,
2,
0,
1,
0,
0
]
},
{
name: 1027,
data: [
0,
2,
18,
2,
0,
0,
0,
0,
0,
0,
1,
0
]
},
{
name: 1028,
data: [
0,
1,
0,
1,
0,
0,
0,
3,
0,
1,
0,
0
]
},
{
name: 1029,
data: [
0,
0,
17,
0,
0,
0,
0,
0,
0,
0,
0,
0
]
},
{
name: 1030,
data: [
1,
1,
5,
0,
2,
0,
2,
1,
0,
1,
0,
2
]
},
{
name: 1031,
data: [
5,
4,
1,
2,
0,
1,
2,
0,
6,
2,
5,
2
]
},
{
name: 1032,
data: [
4,
7,
4,
0,
0,
2,
1,
2,
2,
0,
3,
1
]
},
{
name: 1033,
data: [
5,
2,
19,
1,
1,
0,
0,
1,
3,
1,
6,
4
]
},
{
name: 1034,
data: [
8,
2,
8,
1,
0,
2,
1,
0,
3,
0,
5,
6
]
},
{
name: 1035,
data: [
11,
6,
3,
0,
0,
0,
1,
3,
3,
3,
2,
13
]
},
{
name: 1036,
data: [
0,
3,
7,
0,
0,
0,
1,
1,
0,
4,
0,
3
]
},
{
name: 1039,
data: [
4,
1,
2,
0,
1,
0,
1,
2,
1,
1,
0,
3
]
},
{
name: 5000,
data: [
1,
1,
0,
2,
4,
0,
0,
0,
0,
0,
1,
1
]
},
{
name: 6000,
data: [
0,
0,
1,
4,
1,
0,
0,
0,
0,
0,
0,
0
]
}
]
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="highchart_1"></div>
  </body>
```

Comment: You can set `visible: false` to initially hide certain series. See http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-visible/

Comment: Any way without reworking the API ?

Comment: Sure, use [`Series.hide()`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.hide). It also wouldn't be difficult to add the `visible` flags to your JSON data after fetching it but before injecting it into Highcharts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would just manipulate the JSON data before injecting it into Highcharts.

Assuming your JSON API returns the array of series data...

```
// var series = getSeriesDataViaAjax();
var showTheseIndexes = [0,2,4];

for (var i = 0; i < series.length; i++) {
    if (showTheseIndexes.indexOf(i) === -1) {
        series[i].visible = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

How about disabling all of the series:

```
plotOptions: {
  series: {
    visible: false
  }
}
```

And then in load event showing required series? Like this:

```
chart: {
  events: {
    load: function() {
      this.series[index].show();
    }
  }
}
```

Where `index` is series index which should be displayed.

Comment: I am getting this error : Cannot read property 'show' of undefined

Comment: @RohitBandooni you don't literally use `index`. An example would be if you want index `0` to show, you would use `this.series[0].show()`

Comment: @Phil   I did the same :)