# Wanted to plot only one spline at the chart load and further add other splines after loading

Tags: highcharts

[Main multispline chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BIaXD.png)

HI All, as shown in the image, I am plotting multispline chart using highcharts. What I want is to plot only 'a' while loading the chart and the rest will be invisible and I could add them later like this [Higcharts Spline (only one)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yr3W3.png).
Thank you in advance.
This [previous answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30473296/show-only-some-series-in-highcharts-spline-chart?rq=1) partly working in my case but I don't want to hide all the series. I want to have one visible series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Highcharts.Chart.addSeries()](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#addSeries) method to add additional series dynamically:

Html:

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
<button id="btn">Add series</button>
```

JS:

```
let data = [{
  name: 'Installation',
  data: [43934, 52503, 57177, 69658, 97031, 119931, 137133, 154175]
}, {
  name: 'Manufacturing',
  data: [24916, 24064, 29742, 29851, 32490, 30282, 38121, 40434]
}, {
  name: 'Sales & Distribution',
  data: [11744, 17722, 16005, 19771, 20185, 24377, 32147, 39387]
}, {
  name: 'Project Development',
  data: [null, null, 7988, 12169, 15112, 22452, 34400, 34227]
}, {
  name: 'Other',
  data: [12908, 5948, 8105, 11248, 8989, 11816, 18274, 18111]
}];

let btn = document.querySelector('#btn');
let i = 1;

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (i < data.length) {
    chart.addSeries(data[i]);
    i++;
  }
});

let chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'spline'
  },
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      marker: {
        enabled: false
      },
      pointStart: 2010
    }
  },
  series: [
    data[0]
  ]
});
```

Demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/rtsznykp/3/